# Typescript type for "map of union type values to strings"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary, types, union

There's a `type` defined like this: `type ComponentType = 'CPU' | 'Motherboard' | 'Memory' | 'PSU'`.

I want to create an object that I can use to map a `ComponentType` to display strings, e.g. something like:

```
  const componentTypeToLabel/*: to do*/ = {
    CPU: 'Computer processing unit',
    Motherboard: 'Motherboard',
    Memory: 'Memory',
    PSU: 'Power supply unit',
  };
```

On additional consideration, however, is that this `componentTypeToLabel` will not contain all the possible values of `ComponentType`, only some.

What does the type definition look like for `componentTypeToLabel`? How do I define that type? I'm aware of how to do it if `ComponentType` is an `enum` instead (believe it would be `const componentTypeToLabel: { [key in ComponentType]? : string } = ...`), but not when `ComponentType` is a string union `type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type you're looking for is `Partial<Record<ComponentType, string>>`, or equivalently, `{[K in ComponentType]?: string}`:

```
type ComponentType = 'CPU' | 'Motherboard' | 'Memory' | 'PSU';
const componentTypeToLabel: Partial<Record<ComponentType, string>> = {
  CPU: 'Computer processing unit',
  Motherboard: 'Motherboard',
  Memory: 'Memory',
  PSU: 'Power supply unit',
};
```

Both [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt) and [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt) are built in [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types); you can read more about them in the inline TypeScript handbook links.

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzHAdhFwAq5oF4oDkMACgKoFQA+hAsnMABYQBOARnAIbMAmF1BNCAjjMQfQsQDK5ANwBYAFABjVAGdgUFUlTosOTHAAyHVhAA2ALijEuwAJYczAHgBKEFTyfxtaDNkgANFDqzHYoAOYAfJFQ+ADeilCwZFZEiGAArsAsUGDMcEoQqqph4VAZKHbABAGJUHSMLOxc3KkNTGycPDV1gsKibUIiYrUKSVKkqcRwAO45qhlgYGYg5ZXVowC+MlBAA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `interface` to define the object:

```
interface IComponentType {
  CPU?: string;
  Motherboard?: string;
  Memory?: string;
  PSU?: string;
}
```

Since componentTypeToLabel may not contain all the possible values, we can define them as optional in the interface using the `?`.

Then we can create the object with type:

```
const componentTypeToLabel:IComponentType = {
  CPU: 'Computer processing unit',
  Motherboard: 'Motherboard',
  Memory: 'Memory',
  PSU: 'Power supply unit',
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did not consider using an interface but this option you show would indeed work. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an enum with yours keys and an interface:

```
enum ComponentTypes {
    CPU = 'CPU',
    Motherboard = 'Motherboard',
    Memory = 'Memory',
    PSU = 'PSU'}


type ComponentType = { [key in ComponentTypes]? : string }

const componentTypeToLabel: ComponentType = {
    CPU: 'Computer processing unit',
    Motherboard: 'Motherboard',
    PSU: 'Power supply unit',
    xxx: 'test'  // <--- Not Allow
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=2#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9hADnEoAuAVAno4BnKAbwCgozYAFAVSgF4oByGahgGlPIFk40ALYAE4AjOAEMBAEzqNufQSPES2HMp2AQ4ArNIZqNW5eSgUAyjXoNTVBgF9i9tDmCwEyVCExPphKAG0A1sDaAJYgLkgo6Ni4eAC6APxQAFxQeGgCoQDmUHbEAMYoaVAFEe6euBhwADKiQsAANinwpVFe9CRGzFQpTK5gaIJQiAJwefh4WVBgIMFohlw8-MJikj2ySwqS82RWPRRwAO6DeGCIiPXa07PbUAAe9z0DaQxkAPSvUAA8ALS-UADqACUAPIAOQA4sQbEA)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's helpful to have multiple examples, such as yours, that would work. Appreciate it.